# Major Arraylist Trouble

Tags: java

I am new to arraylists and I'm not sure what is wrong and what to do to fix it. Here is the working "consumer curve" that is an array. But the "producer curve" is an array list. I have no idea how to fix this. please help.

ConsumerCurve:

```
  public ConsumerCurve(int np, double m, double b, int dx)
{
     myConsumerCurve = new Point [np];

    for(int i=0; i<np; i++)
    {
        int x = i*dx;
        double y = m*x+b;
        if(y<0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        myConsumerCurve[i] = new Point (x,y);
    }   
}
```

ProducerCurve:

```
public ProducerCurve(int np, double m, double b, int dx)
    {

    for(int i=0; i<np; i++)
    {
        int x = i*dx;
        double y = m*x+b;
        if(y<0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        ArrayList<Point> myProducerCurve = new Point (x,y);
    }   
    }
```

Also, I am getting an error here,says index cannot be resolved to a variable

```
public ProducerCurve()
    {
      Point x;
      myProducerCurve.add(x);
      myProducerCurve.add(index,x);
    }
```

Lastly, how do I add a point to an arraylist that first searches to see if the point exits already and then bubblesorts them?

add():

```
    public void add(Point p)
{
     myProducerCurve.add(p);
}
```

searchPoint:

```
  public int searchPoint(Point p)
{
    for(int index=0; index< myProducerCurve.size(); index++ )
    {
         myProducerCurve.equals(p); 
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList` or `List#toArray` ... but a better choice would be to get the code just use `List`

Comment: You keep on saying that you're getting an error here and there. I see many things wrong with your codes. Have you even looked at the errors and guessed what might be wrong?

Comment: @Mohammad Najar Yeah I have and I don't understand them because this is the first time I'm working with arraylists so I am not quite sure how to fix them

Comment: You need to post your error messages so we could tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @retrogirl19 paste the error message from the output console.

Comment: @MohammadNajar I just did in the edit

Comment: @retrogirl19 you need to paste the error message EXACTLY as it's displayed on the output console. Or you need to point out the line of code that am error is happening. This question to me looks like a school assignment that is due soon and needs immediate attention by others.

Comment: @MohammadNajar What I put is exctly what was displayed. While the fact that this is an assignment is true, I still don't understand how these arraylist things work. They were not taught and are required for the assignment. Though I have tried looking up things via internet and trying to understand them I still don't fully understand. Thus I came here in search of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is on this line:

```
ArrayList<Point> myProducerCurve = new Point (x,y);
```

It should be

```
ArrayList<Point> myProducerCurve = new ArrayList<Point>();
myProducerCurve.add(new Point(x, y));
```

This is due to Java's type system. You try to instanitate `myProducerCurve` to be a new `Point`, but in reality that variable is built to hold data for an `ArrayList` of `Points`

Comment: This helps so much! After fixing that I found other problems I'm not sure how to fix.... see edit

Comment: @retrogirl19 I think there are some fundamentals of ArrayLists that you don't really fully understand, and there's nothing wrong with that! Take a few steps back and re-learn everything carefully